# Como acessar img de um figure JQUERY?

Tags: jquery

Eu quero pegar o `$(figure img).attr('src');` atual, mas o editor ta dizendo que isso é errado e não vai funcionar. como fazer isso funcionar?

CODIGO HTML:

```
<figure class="effect-oscar  wowload fadeInUp" fotografo='Jessiane'>
        <img src="http://iphotochannel.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/15_1.jpg" class='caraDoFotografo' width="450" height="297" alt="img01"/>
        <figcaption>
            <h2>Jessiane</h2>

            <p>FotoGrafia É Vida <br>
            2 FOTOS<BR>

        <a href=''>Ver Fotos</a>          
        </figcaption>

    </figure>
```

Tenho esse `JS` assim, ele está errado ali em `$(this img)`:

```
$('figure').on('click',function() {
    ft = $(this).attr('fotografo');
link = $(this img).attr('src');
window.location.href='blend/portfolio.php?fotografo='+ft+'&link='+link;

});
```

Comment: Boa tarde Deny, a [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/278915/3635) resolveu o problema? Precisa de algo mais?

Answer (score 1):

O erro é que você tem que entender o que é *string* e o que não é *string*, se passar assim sem as aspas:

```
$(figure img).attr('src');
```

É como se esperasse uma variável chamada `figure`, o correto deve ser com as aspas:

```
$('figure img').attr('src');
```

Isto também esta errado, pois você esta querendo misturar o `this` que é um objeto nativo do javascript para acesso do escopo com a palavra `img`:

```
$(this img).attr('src');
```

O certo provavelmente seria isto:

```
$('figure').on('click',function() {
    var ft = $(this).attr('fotografo');
    var link = $('img', this).attr('src');
    window.location.href='blend/portfolio.php?fotografo='+ft+'&link='+link;
});
```

O `this` é passado depois da virgula para que altere o "contexto" dos seletores na função `$(...)` do jQuery, ou seja ao invés de usar o seletor `'img'` no `document.` ele vai usar no `<figure>` que você clicou, como é explicado na documentação:

- http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery1

Comment: Correto, o uso semântico seria  dessa forma `var link = $('img', this).attr('src');`, se me permite, irei re-editar a minha resposta acrescentando esse modo.

Answer (score 0):

Para selecionar o `atributo` `src`, faça da seguinte forma:

```
link = $('figure img').attr('src');
```

Você não pode acessar da forma que está fazendo `link = $(this img).attr('src');` pois `img` não está envolvida entre aspas, então o navegador não consegue achar a referência, e outra, não se pode misturar o `this` com um elemento `html` desse modo que você está fazendo.

Para utilizar o `this` da forma adequada nessa situação, o certo seria `var link = $('img', this).attr('src');` como o Guilherme citou.

Answer (score -1):

Tente realizar trocando pela classe da foto:

```
$('.caraDoFotografo').attr('src');
```